# Rust Nom: many and end of input

Tags: rust, nom

I'm trying to get familiar with Nom, currently version 5, where there is no `CompleteStr` and other things, so related questions aren't so helpful.

How can I parse something like

```
"@pook Some free text @another_pook And another text"
```

into

```
vec![("pook", "Some free text"), ("another_pook", "And another text")]
```

?

`@` prepended strings are called "field identifiers";
next substring is a description;
both are called "field"

Here is how I parse one field successfully:

```
use nom::bytes::complete::take_while1;
use nom::*;
use nom::character::is_alphabetic;

fn ident(c: char) -> bool {
    is_alphabetic(c as u8) || c == '_'
}

fn freetext(c: char) -> bool {
    c != '@'
}

fn parse_ident(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    take_while1(ident)(s)
}

fn parse_freetext(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    take_while1(freetext)(s)
}


named! {field_ident<&str, &str>,
    do_parse!(
        tag!("@") >>
        name: parse_ident >>
        (name)
    )
}

named! { field <&str, (&str, &str)>,
    do_parse!(
        name: ws!(field_ident) >>
        description: parse_freetext >>
        (name, description)
    )
}
```

When I wrap it into `many1` and provide input as stated in the beginning I receive `Err(Incomplete(Size(1)))`, but it works if I put `@` in the end of the input. How can I mark it as completed on the end of input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `many_till` combinator, not `many1`, like so:

```rust
use nom::bytes::complete::take_while1;
use nom::character::is_alphabetic;
use nom::*;

fn ident(c: char) -> bool {
    is_alphabetic(c as u8) || c == '_'
}

fn freetext(c: char) -> bool {
    c != '@'
}

fn parse_ident(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    take_while1(ident)(s)
}

fn parse_freetext(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    take_while1(freetext)(s)
}

named! {field_ident<&str, &str>,
    do_parse!(
        tag!("@") >>
        name: parse_ident >>
        (name)
    )
}

named! { field <&str, (&str, &str)>,
    do_parse!(
        name: ws!(field_ident) >>
        description: parse_freetext >>
        (name, description)
    )
}

named!(fields<&str, (Vec<(&str, &str)>, &str)>, many_till!(field, eof!()));

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", field("@pook Some free text"));
    println!(
        "{:?}",
        fields("@pook Some free text @another_pook And another text")
    );
}
```

Rather counter-intuitive. It has to do with the streaming nature of `nom`, I guess.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried and now I have TakeWhile1 error. I'll rewrite to functions to do something with the "streaming nature".

Comment: Update the answer to include full source code. It works for me.

Comment: Oh my bad, I left that `@` in the end, now it works, thank you!